# Why do we multiply by 100 for finding percentage?

Tags: arithmetic

1. For example, if there are 50 boys in a school and the total number of students is $200$ then, for finding percentage of boys why do we do like this, $\left(\, 50/200\, \right)100\ \% = 25\ \%$ ?.
2. Why does the fraction '$50/200$' represent ?. I know 'percentage' means out of $100$ but $50/200$ is not representing $50$ out of hundred ?.

Comment: $25$% or $25$ for each $100$. For example if we have $50$ seniors and $200$ high school students, then we have $25$ seniors for each $100$ high school students, and that is $25$% seniors.

Comment: Multiplying by $100\%$ equals to multiplying by $ 100 × 1/100$, that is $1$, and that is doing nothing. Instead, try to "factor out" a $1/100$ term just as you can swap "1 mile" and "1.609 km" in any physics equation. So: $50/200=25/100 = 25 × 1/100 = 25\%$.

Comment: Per cent means for every 100. So we multiply by 100 to see how much we get for one group of 100.

Comment: Because "percent" means $\frac{1}{100}$.

Comment: 50/200 is not representing 50 out of 100 because 50/200 is not 50%.  It is 25 % and it absolutely does indeed represent 25 out of 100.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*In response to suggested edits...*

Read  "50 boys in a school and the total number of students is 200"

as 50 boys out of 200 students

which is represented by the fraction $\dfrac{50}{200}$

Converting to percents means converting to a fraction with a denominator of 100.

Which is to say

$$\dfrac{50}{200} = \dfrac{x}{100}$$

Which becomes $$x= 100\times \dfrac{50}{200}$$

Comment: It's  a good proof and it would be better if you prove it for any fraction $\frac{x}{y}$ though it is clear from your answer.

Answer (score 3):

When you take a portion and divide it by the whole, you create a value that must always be less than or equal to 1.

Let $w$ represent the whole.

Let $p$ represent the portion such that $p \underline{<} w$.

Therefore, $\frac{p}{w} \underline{<} 1$.

When $\frac{p}{w}$ is multiplied by 100, you're just scaling the decimal to I guess what you might consider a more user-friendly, comprehensive value. The ratio is still the same, of course.

The word percent actually comes from the Latin *per centum*, which means per one hundred. So instead of visualizing data in terms of values greater than $100$, such as in your case, ratios can be scaled to a denominator of $100$, simplifying all data to a more comprehensible manner.

$50$%, $75$%, and $90$% are easier to compare than $\frac{2234}{4468}$, $\frac{2935929}{3914572}$, and $\frac{37901171181738.6}{42112412424154}$. By multipling these fractions by $100$, they are set standardized and thus much easier to compare and contrast with other standardized values.

Answer (score 2):

I saw Steven 's answer and it is describing the case correctly.

We can prove it in general also:-

Let $\frac{a}{b}$ be fraction then to find percentage which is out of hundred we have to find the equivalent numerator of the percentage.
n would be our numerator in this case:-

$$\frac{a}{b} = \frac{n}{100}$$

Then,

$$\frac{a}{b} • 100 = n $$

And we got why would we multiply by hundred to get percentage.